# Electrical wiring 14-2 wire connect 12-2 wire

Tags: electrical

My outlets are 14-2 NM wire, wired into the attic, is it ok to connect a  12-2 NM wire to the 14-2 wires and connect them to the panel box w a 15amp breaker???

Comment: Even though it may be legal, why would you do that?

Comment: multiple issues, id rather not share here...thx I have  marked the breaker and the wires in more than one place that it has both 14-2 and 12-2 wires connected....

Comment: I think "not" a duplicate because in this case he has the proper breaker which is really core to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the 12 awg wire on a 15 amp circuit connecting the section that is wired in 14.
 The only problem and I have found with this in the past where part was wired in 14 but the breaker had #12 , I am guessing that at a later date someone put in a 20a breaker and cooked the 14 gauge wireing because it looked like it was wired with 12 at the panel.

Comment: that is exactly my concern. I guess there isn't actually a code prohibition to protect against this sort of future confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's no problem using larger wire (as long as it fits in any terminals/connectors), since thicker gauge wire can carry larger amounts of current.

Comment: There is an issue - it is harder to make a good, solid connection between wires of different diameters, especially when using wire nuts (as opposed to a wago). The solution is to be careful, make good connections, and use a wago if you doubt your wire twisting abilities.

Comment: @Adonalsium I've never had any trouble using properly sized twist-on wire connectors.

Comment: @Adonalsium never had that problem before, except when trying to re-use ratty old Scotchloks, which are not made for reuse.   And I often mix solid and stranded too.  If your nuts aren't working for you, either use modern good ones (e.g. ideal's Wingnuts) and use them correctly.